# MVC how to fill form from different model

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have table with Name,Surname, city and Address. (Model, View, Controler- strongly typed)
When I click on some record I want to open another form with 
Name,Surname, city and Address and Parent name, but I need 
Name,Surname, city and Address to be filled with data from record clicked.
Model is strongly typed.

It's need to be done with two models.
My question is- how to pass data from one model to another (the best way).

Comment: Use a copy constructor.

Comment: Look into Automapper?

Comment: You can use `lodash` for such things..the use `_find` like in this example: https://lodash.com/docs#find